# Java hash table based on open addressing implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve task from hash tables and I'm stuck.
I need to describe a hash table based on open addressing. Linear probing is used to resolve collisions.
I need to implement insert method:

*-void insert(int key, Object value)
Inserts a key/value pair in the hash table if the key is missing or replaces the object if the key exists*

Conditions:
-The initial capacity of the hash table is 8 buckets.
-The maximum capacity is 16; inserting more elements should raise an IllegalStateException.
-The capacity should double each time a new element arrives and all the buckets are already occupied. -For example, if 8 buckets are already filled and a new key is about to be added, the capacity should increase.

Use any type from the java.util package or its subpackages, except for the java.util.Iterator is forbidden.

```
public class HashtableOpen8to16Impl implements HashtableOpen8to16 {
    
    int capacity;
    int size;

    static HashNode[] hashTable;

    public HashtableOpen8to16Impl() {
        hashTable = new HashNode[8];
        this.capacity = 8;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    private static class HashNode {
        int key;
        Object value;

        public HashNode(int key, Object value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(int key, Object value) {
        HashNode temp = new HashNode(key, value);

        if (size == 0) {
            hashTable = nullConverter();
        }

        if (size == capacity-1) {
            doubleCapacity();
        }

        int hashIndex = abs(key) % capacity;
        while (hashTable[hashIndex].key != 0 && hashTable[hashIndex].key != temp.key && hashTable[hashIndex].key != -1) {
            hashIndex++;
            hashIndex %= capacity;
        }
        if (hashTable[hashIndex].key == 0 || hashTable[hashIndex].key == -1) {
            if (!hashTable[hashIndex].value.equals(temp.value)) {
                size++;
            }
        }

        hashTable[hashIndex] = temp;
    }

    public void doubleCapacity() {
        capacity = 16;
        HashNode[] tempHashTable = nullConverter();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashTable.length; i++) {
            tempHashTable[i] = hashTable[i];
        }
        hashTable = tempHashTable;

    }

    public HashNode[] nullConverter() {
        HashNode[] tempHashTable = new HashNode[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            tempHashTable[i] = new HashNode(0, 0);
        }
        return tempHashTable;
    }
}
```

There are 8 test cases where key=value:

```
1. Input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
   Expected [16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
   Correct
2. Input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   Expected [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,0,0,0,0]
   Correct
3. Input [-74,98,-44,75,-27,76,-33,42,-71,77]
   Expected [77, -33, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, -71, 0, 0, 42, -74, -44, 75, -27, 76]
   Actual [0, -33, -74, 98, -44, 75, -27, 76, -71, 0, 42, 0, 0, 77, 0, 0]
4. Input [70,-17,-46,-80,53,-94,-76,-7]
   Expected [-80, -17, -94, -7, -76, 53, 70, -46]
   Actual [-80, -17, -94, 0, -76, 53, 70, -46, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5. Input [43,-77,-81,-20,14,-49,39,46,-69,-19,-37,-92,44,13,74]
   Expected [44, -81, -49, -19, -20, -69, -37, 39, 13, 0, 74, 43, -92, -77, 46, 14]
   Actual [0, -81, -49, 43, -20, -77, 14, 39, -69, -19, -37, 74, -92, 44, 46, 13]
6. Input [30,19,-61,-34,78,78,-34,80,30,19,-61,48,68,48,80,68]
   Expected [80, 48, -34, 19, 68, -61, 30, 78]
   Actual [80, 48, -34, 19, 68, -61, 30, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7. Input [0,5,-70,0,-9,0,95,25,0,-3,-14,79,0,-62,45,0,88,0,49]
   Expected [0, 79, -62, -3, 49, 5, -70, 0, 88, -9, 25, 0, 0, 45, -14, 95]
   Actual [-14, -9, 25, -3, 49, 5, -70, 95, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, -62, 79]
8. Input [0,0,8,0,8,16,32,24,256,0,0,8,16]
   Expected [0, 8, 16, 32, 24, 256, 0, 0]
   Actual [8, 16, 32, 24, 256, 0, 0, 0]
```

First 2 tests are ok but rest are wrong. Where is mistake in my implementation? How it supposed to look like?

Comment: You simply copy the old entries into the new doubled array, but I suspect you're expected to re-hash the values. Since the table size changed, the new position of entries should potentially change as well.

Comment: In addition to what @user16320675 mentioned: 4) why is `hashTable` declared `static` when it is supposed to hold the object’s state? 5) why do you initialize `hashTable` with an array in the constructor when you overwrite it with the result of `nullConverter()` on the first invocation of `insert` anyway? 6) if you use a zero key as initial state/absent value, how is the code supposed to ever handle an actual zero key? 7) Be aware of the limitations of [`Math.abs(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)), i.e. it can return a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

> *In addition to what @user16320675 mentioned: 4) why is hashTable declared static when it is supposed to hold the object’s state? 5) why do you initialize hashTable with an array in the constructor when you overwrite it with the result of nullConverter() on the first invocation of insert anyway? 6) if you use a zero key as initial state/absent value, how is the code supposed to ever handle an actual zero key? 7) Be aware of the limitations of Math.abs(…), i.e. it can return a negative value.*

Second rehashing during increasing capacity and converter from null to 0 moved to another method make it works. Thanks guys!